# How to process VPS SPS and PPS from extra data in ffmpeg av_read_frame

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-processing, hevc

I am developing c++ code to read Hevc mp4 file and convert in to rtsp stream for playback using ffmpeg lib.

```
            if ((ret = av_read_frame(m_fmctx, &m_pkt)) < 0)
                return re;
```

I can able to read file get the packets but cant able to get Vps,Sps and Pps .
Is there a way to extract the  parameter set?
if we can then whats the size and position of this  parameter set.

Answer (score 0):

[There might be simpler solutions than what I'm suggesting]

Solution 1: Read the bitstream yourself

VPS, SPS and PPS are written in the MP4 configuration record, right after `lengthSizeMinusOne`. There, you may read 8 bits to get the number of xPS written in the stream (e.g. 3), then in a loop, you can access them one by one. See the syntax in [ISO/IEC 14496-15:2021](https://dms.mpeg.expert/doc_end_user/documents/133_OnLine/wg11/MDS19981_WG03_N00149.zip) at Section **8.3.3.1.2 Syntax**.

Solution 2: Use a software

You can simply install [MP4Box](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/MP4Box) and dump the configuration record, using `-dxml` on your MP4 file. In the log file, you can identify VPS, SPS and PPS by their NALU numbers

Comment: ISO/IEC 14496-15:2021  the site is asking user name and password